# How to clean data from Excel with Python at scale?

Tags: python, excel, data-cleaning

Each month I load a company's financials into a master workbook which flows into our forecasting model managed in Excel. These exports are large, generally 20,000 rows per month and the current file is becoming slow and harder to use.

As part of this exercise, I ensure all transactions are mapped against the appropriate "Account" and "Class" - sometimes there were errors when the data was initial entered into our accounting software. I have written logic in Excel to automatically clean part of this data and have already created "Override" columns to so I can manually edit the Class/Account of certain transactions. Part of this process involves filtering on certain columns and spot checking the Classes/Accounts to identify errors - for example, all accounts that start with "40" are related to revenue, and should have the appropriate revenue classes. Similarly, this applies across the data set and there are 5-10 other checks I perform to clean the data.

Additionally, some of these transactions are tagged to the wrong account (see row 7) and I review a brief memo about the transaction and will validate (however, I do not do this for all 20,000/month).

I have some experience with Python and Pandas and am looking to perform this exercise in Python to improve my data cleaning skills.

My concern is that although many errors are caught with the index/match cross reference table, there is a decent amount of work associated with ensure all revenue/cost of good sold/expense accounts are tagged accurately (we have about 200 different "Accounts" and over 20 "Classes" in our chart of accounts - and even when I do write the script to identify the one-off errors, would I have to utilize loc/iloc in pandas to identify the specific transaction index/ID, then write another one-off line of code to make the edit and append it to the data frame, then comment it out continue parsing?

My intuition is to write out each step in the process as I complete it manually then write a script/line(s) of code to address each one of those checks - can't help but feel like I am potentially missing something and this approach is not scalable because this exercise occurs each month. Looking for any guidance from folks who might have to clean and append a data set routinely vs. one-off.

Apologies for the long description and thanks for any guidance!

[image: Sample data set]

[image: Sample data set with formulas]

Comment: Not someone who has done this but, the way i would tackle it would be to write code for every check you do, so basically just a bunch of if statements, then loop it for every row. You can use [openpyexcel](https://pypi.org/project/openpyexcel/) to get excel in python

Comment: I think my approach given that it's financial and maybe needs to be auditable would be scan the sheet, apply the checks and create an error report. Manually update the error report with the corrections. On  next run apply the corrections before repeating the checks and creating another error report. Repeat until no errors. At the end you have an original file, a series of error correcting files and a final clean file. I have a proof-of-concept script if you think this is viable.